# Passing Php Variable to another variable using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this JS/jQuery code

```
window.onload = function(){

    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/test.php",
    type: "GET",            
    dataType: "html"
    //data: {$lastid},
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $(".recent-orders").append(msg);
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
EDIT: This is the method where I get the $lastid.


<?php
function woocommerce_dashboard_recent_orders() {

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => 8,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
        'post_status'     => 'publish'
    );
    $orders = get_posts( $args );
    if ($orders) :
    echo '<ul class="recent-orders">';
        foreach ($orders as $order) :

            $this_order = new WC_Order( $order->ID );

            echo '
            <li>
                <span id = "order-$order->ID" class="order-status '.sanitize_title($this_order->status).'">'.ucwords(__($this_order->status, 'woocommerce')).'</span> <a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$order->ID).'&action=edit">' . get_the_time( __( 'l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID ) . '</a><br />
                <small>'.sizeof($this_order->get_items()).' '._n('item', 'items', sizeof($this_order->get_items()), 'woocommerce').' <span class="order-cost">'.__('Total:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . woocommerce_price($this_order->order_total).'</span></small>
            </li>';

        endforeach;
        $lastid = $order->ID;
        echo '</ul>';
    else:
        echo '<p>' . __( 'There are no product orders yet.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
    endif;
}
?>
```

That calls a php file called test.php.

test.php

```
    <?php
//woocommerce_dashboard_recent_orders_realtime();

/**
 * Init the dashboard widgets.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */

function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $oid = 2100;
    $where = " AND ID > $oid";

    return $where;

}


add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => 8,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' =>  FALSE
    );

    $orders = get_posts( $args );

    if ($orders) :
        foreach ($orders as $order) :
            //echo " $order->ID";
            $this_order = new WC_Order( $order->ID );
            echo '
            <li>
                <span id = "order-$order->ID" class="order-status '.sanitize_title($this_order->status).'">'.ucwords(__($this_order->status, 'woocommerce')).'</span> <a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$order->ID).'&action=edit">' . get_the_time( __( 'l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID ) . '</a><br />
                <small>'.sizeof($this_order->get_items()).' '._n('item', 'items', sizeof($this_order->get_items()), 'woocommerce').' <span class="order-cost">'.__('Total:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . woocommerce_price($this_order->order_total).'</span></small>
            </li>';

            //echo (gettype($time3));
        endforeach;

    endif;
//}
?>
```

What I want to do is to pass the $lastid from the javascript to the test.php file and receive it as something like $lastid also.

I know I should post, but I'm having trouble using it. Can anyone lead me to the right method?

My CODE now

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
window.onload = function(){
    //setInterval(function(){
        //var lastid = '<?php echo $lastid; ?>';
        //alert(lastid);
        var request = $.ajax({
        url: "../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/test.php",
        type: "POST",      
        dataType: "html",
        data: { lastid : '<?php echo $lastid; ?>'},
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            $(".recent-orders").append(msg);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
        //addElement();

    //},1000);
setInterval(function(){


},1000);

}

</script>

<?php
function woocommerce_dashboard_recent_orders() {

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => 8,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'ASC',
        'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
        'post_status'     => 'publish'
    );
    $orders = get_posts( $args );
    if ($orders) :
    echo '<ul class="recent-orders">';
        foreach ($orders as $order) :

            $this_order = new WC_Order( $order->ID );

            echo '
            <li>
                <span id = "order-$order->ID" class="order-status '.sanitize_title($this_order->status).'">'.ucwords(__($this_order->status, 'woocommerce')).'</span> <a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$order->ID).'&action=edit">' . get_the_time( __( 'l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID ) . '</a><br />
                <small>'.sizeof($this_order->get_items()).' '._n('item', 'items', sizeof($this_order->get_items()), 'woocommerce').' <span class="order-cost">'.__('Total:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . woocommerce_price($this_order->order_total).'</span></small>
            </li>';

        endforeach;
        $lastid = $order->ID;
        echo '</ul>';
    else:
        echo '<p>' . __( 'There are no product orders yet.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
    endif;
}
?>

<?php
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $oid = 2110;
    $where = " AND ID > $oid";

    return $where;

}

$lastid = $_GET['lastid'];

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => 8,
        'orderby'         => 'post_date',
        'order'           => 'DESC',
        'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' =>  FALSE
    );


    $orders = get_posts( $args );
    echo "LAST ID: $lastid";
    if ($orders) :
        foreach ($orders as $order) :
            $this_order = new WC_Order( $order->ID );


            echo '
            <li>
                <span id = "order-$order->ID" class="order-status '.sanitize_title($this_order->status).'">'.ucwords(__($this_order->status, 'woocommerce')).'</span> <a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$order->ID).'&action=edit">' . get_the_time( __( 'l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $order->ID ) . '</a><br />
                <small>'.sizeof($this_order->get_items()).' '._n('item', 'items', sizeof($this_order->get_items()), 'woocommerce').' <span class="order-cost">'.__('Total:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . woocommerce_price($this_order->order_total).'</span></small>
            </li>';

        endforeach;

    endif;
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
//}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand if I understand your question, but it seems like your first page has already evaluated $lastId, most likely from an insert query... and you want to also set it to a javascript variable, while also using post method. Assuming all that this is how I would for the first page

```
<script>
var $lastid = <?php echo $lastid ?>;

...

window.onload = function(){

var request = $.ajax({
url: "../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/test.php",
type: "POST",            
dataType: "html"
data: {"lastid":$lastid},
});

request.done(function(msg) {
    $(".recent-orders").append(msg);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

....

</script>
```

Then on the second page use this to access the post

```
<?php
$lastid = $_POST['lastid'];
?>
```

That is how you do post in php hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the original code

```
...
url: "../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/test.php?lastid=2098"
...
```

Then in test.php, access the variable using

```
$lastid = $_GET['lastid'];
```

There are several other ways that this can be done, this is just a quick and dirty method.

Comment: It works, but how can I change the "2098" into a variable? since the $lastid in the javascript is actually dynamic it increases so I should really pass the variable. There's more to the code but they are kinda irrelevant.

Comment: @user3295330 in that case you have to assign the value to a variable (like `var lastid = '<?php echo $lastid; ?>';` then you can change it how many times you want like this: `lastid = some_new_value` (or simply `lastid++` if you want to increase the value with one)).

Comment: @user3295330 and when sending it just use this code: `url: '../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/test.php?lastid='+lastid,`

Comment: @DanielLisik I tried doing this var lastid = '<?php echo $lastid ?>'; and alert(lastid); it shows an empty string.

Comment: @user3295330 can you try with: `var lastid = '<?php echo $lastid; ?>';`? Also, make sure you didn't define `lastid` before that code.

Comment: @DanielLisik I added the method where I get the $lastid so people could understand, I'm sorry if I caused any confusion,

Comment: @RichardSon try putting `var lastid = '<?php echo $lastid; ?>';` before `var request = $.ajax({ ...`

Comment: @DanielLisik That is actually what I did,

Comment: @RichardSon, any of the methods mentioned by Daniel Lisik should work. More importantly, ensure that `$lastid` is declared before the Ajax call. I didn't bother using the variable in my answer because your code portrayed $lastid as a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Send the variable:

Change:

```
//data: {$lastid},
```

to:

```
data: { lastid : '<?php echo $lastid; ?>'},
```

**2.** Get variable in *test.php*:

```
$lastid = $_GET['lastid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
var lastId = <?php echo $lastId; ?>;
var request = $.ajax({
url: "../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/admin/test.php" + "?lastid=" + lastId,
type: "GET",            
dataType: "html"
//data: {$lastid},
});

request.done(function(msg) {
    $(".recent-orders").append(msg);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

on test.php add this line

```
$lastId = $_GET['lastid'];
```